# On a derivation of a concentration inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am following Tao's notes on concentration of measures that can be found [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/#s-large).

I don't understand, in the below given notes, how Tao passes from $(7)$ to $(8)$, in particular how an exponential shows up, could anybody clarify this for me?

[image: tao]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of passing from $(7)$ to $(8)$ is to look at the function
$$f(k)=2\left(\frac{\sqrt{ek/2}}{\lambda}\right)^k$$
and to note that it has a global minimum (to this Tao refers when he is talking about "optimizing") at $k_0=\frac{2\lambda^2}{e^2}$, for which the corresponding value is
$$f(k_0)=e^{-\lambda^2/e^2}$$
leading to the inequality $(8)$, provided that $k_0$ lies in the range indicated by $(6)$. To check this, you'll have to tell us what $K$ is.